# pwd to return current path with "/" at the end

Tags: bash, pwd

I want `pwd` to return `/path/to/dir` in the format `/path/to/dir/` with the "`/`" at the end. Any ideas as to how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `bash4.4+`, you could redefine `pwd` as:

```
pwd() {
  local -
  set -o pipefail
  builtin pwd "$@" | sed '${/\/$/!s|$|/|;}'
}
```

That is add a `/` to the last line of the current working directory if it was not there already (like after `cd /`) and return the original exit status thanks to the `pipefail` option (turned on for that function only with `local -`).

(with `zsh`, replace `local -; set -o pipefail` with `set -o localoptions -o pipefail`).

POSIXly, you could do:

```
pwd() (
  pwd=$(command pwd "$@" && echo .) || exit
  pwd=${pwd%??}
  pwd=${pwd%/}/
  printf '%s\n' "$pwd"
)
```

Comment: That sort of worked. Every time I now use `pwd` I also get "bash: local: `-': not a valid identifier" before the path is returned in the next line.

Comment: @E.l4d3, as I said, it's for bash 4.4 or above. You probably have an older version. Then use the POSIX variant.